# Questions on linear regression of multiple outputs with correlated errors

Tags: regression, self-study, multiple-regression, linear-model

This is a questions regarding the linear regression of multiple outputs with correlated errors.

Let us consider multiple outputs $Y_1, \cdots, Y_k$ that we wish to predict from inputs $X_0, X_1, \cdots, X_p$. We assume linear model for each output that $$Y_k = \beta_{0k} + \sum_{j=1}^p X_j \beta_{jk} + \epsilon_k = f_k(X) + \epsilon_k.$$ When having $N$ observations, we denote these models using matrix notation as $$Y = XB + E$$ where $X\in \mathbb{R}^{N\times (p + 1)}$, $B\in \mathbb{R}^{(p + 1) \times K}$ and $Y\in \mathbb{R}^{N\times K}$. It is a well-known results that when $\epsilon_i$'s are uncorrelated and of zero-mean and unit-variance, then the solution of minimizing $RSS(B) = \mathrm{tr} [(Y - XB)^\intercal (Y-XB)]$ is given by $$\hat{B} = (X^\intercal X)^{-1}X^\intercal Y.$$

My question comes when $\epsilon_i$'s are correlated. Suppose that $\mathrm{Cov}(\epsilon) = \Sigma$ with $\epsilon = (\epsilon_1, \cdots, \epsilon_K)$ for all observations. In this case, we aim to find $B$ that minimizes $$RSS(B, \Sigma) = \sum_{i = 1}^N (y_i - f(x_i))^\intercal \Sigma^{-1} (y_i - f(x_i)),$$ where $y_i$ and $x_i$ are the vector notation for observation $i$.

It was claimed in *Elements of Statistical Learning* by Hastie that the solution remains to be $\hat{B} = (X^\intercal X)^{-1}X^\intercal Y$ (see Exercise 3.11 or Page 56). However, I'm having trouble getting this result. I had $$RSS(B, \Sigma) = \mathrm{tr} [(Y - XB)^\intercal \Sigma^{-1} (Y-XB)] = \mathrm{tr}[(\Sigma^{-\frac{1}{2}}Y - \Sigma^{-\frac{1}{2}}XB)^\intercal (\Sigma^{-\frac{1}{2}}Y-\Sigma^{-\frac{1}{2}}XB)].$$ Therefore, with the correlated error, I suppose the solution should be
\begin{align*}
\hat{B} &= ((\Sigma^{-\frac{1}{2}}X)^\intercal (X\Sigma^{-\frac{1}{2}}))^{-1}(\Sigma^{-\frac{1}{2}}X)^\intercal \Sigma^{-\frac{1}{2}}Y \\
&= (X^\intercal \Sigma^{-1} X)^{-1} X^\intercal \Sigma^{-1}Y,
\end{align*}

which is different from what was claimed in the book. Am I missing anything?

Comment: The Wikipedia article on Seemingly Unrelated Regression https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seemingly_unrelated_regressions should help answer your question.

Comment: @jbowman Thanks for the wiki! If I'm understanding it correctly, it seems that the claim from Hastie that "the solution for correlated error case remains the same" is incorrect?

Comment: No, it is correct.  Looking at your first equation, you'll see that every regression has the same regressors, so you are in situation #2 under "Equivalence to OLS."

Comment: I'm not super familiar with the SUR method here. The formulation I used in this question was stacking multiple outputs column-wise. And in your wiki, it seems that the multiple outputs are stacked row-wise? This would potentially affect the closed-form solution of $\hat{\beta}$, right?

Comment: If you stack the outputs columnwise, you'll get one $\hat{beta}$ vector for everything UNLESS you create copies of the $X$ matrix and arrange them in a block diagonal form in a new matrix of regressors.  But since the blocks are identical, they still fall under situation #2.